# "WARNING: configuration operation applied only to a subset of architectures" during kernel recompile

Tags: kernel, compiling, 22.10

As I've been doing for a while now, after every Ubuntu-provided kernel update (for security, etc.) - I'm needing to recompile the kernel for a test VM to include some drivers that are otherwise missing from the default config (nor even included as modules).

While following the instructions detailed at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel, at the end of every run of `editconfigs`, I'm getting the following warning / error:

```
check-config: 11330/11330 checks passed -- exit 0

WARNING: configuration operation applied only to a subset of architectures (skipped armhf arm64 ppc64el riscv64 s390x)

make: *** [debian/rules.d/1-maintainer.mk:43: editconfigs] Error 1
```

Regardless, continuing with the next `LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary` command succeeds.  However, it seems quite haphazard to proceed past this warning / error - which also results in an exit code of 2 back to the command-line, and prevents further scripting this without completely ignoring the issue.  I'm also not doing anything (at least not that I know of) to "skip" these other architectures (assuming there was maybe an option to configure them without even cross-compiling them).

I do see the comment on the above documentation page about:

```
# you need to go through each (Y, Exit, Y, Exit..) or get a complaint about config later
```

... however, while I do recall seeing the repeated menus at some point months back on prior kernel versions, I'm only ever seeing the one edit for "amd64":

```
$ LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
dh_testdir;
conc_level=-j4 /bin/bash -e debian/scripts/misc/kernelconfig editconfigs "true"
Do you want to edit config: amd64/config.flavour.generic? [Y/n]
```

I've seen this on at least Ubuntu kernels 5.19.0-23.24, 5.19.0-35.36, and 5.19.0-38.39, so far.

How can I resolve this warning / error?  Or maybe otherwise completely disable even the existence of these other architectures in my build?

Comment: Are you using an ARM processor? If not its a message not an error.

Comment: @David - No, amd64.  It's still an error; it ends with "Error 1" and 2 as a non-0 return status / exit code.

Comment: Since you are not using ARM messages about ARM are not important to you.

Comment: @David - have you run through this process yourself?  If so, I'd be curious to see if you're getting the same warning and error.  I can otherwise only find to references to them on a web search, and without any resolution that I can see.  Also if so, I'd then have something else I'd like you to see - with as I mentioned, this breaks further attempts to automate this, without ignoring all potential errors and missing other potential errors that are more significant.

Comment: @guiverc - My apologies, I mis-tagged (and now corrected) the version posted here.  I'm on the latest and greatest 22.10.